# Ninja Forms - reject form submission with a generic error, not a field-specific error

Tags: wordpress, ninja-forms

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48063223/custom-validation-ninja-form-with-error-handle) about how to return a custom validation error on form submit. This works for individual field errors, but how do I return a generic form error not pertaining to a particular field? I want to return a custom form submission error that appears above the submit button. The error I want to return doesn't have anything to do with a specific field, so I want to send back a generic error message that just shows at the bottom of the form.

There's no documentation on this that I can find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First set your custom error to *$form_data['errors']* in your submit hook.

`$form_data['errors'] = ["My Custom Error Message"];`

Now you need to display this error using front-end code.
Hook into `"submit:response"` on the front-end.

```js
var mySubmitController = Marionette.Object.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    this.listenTo(
      Backbone.Radio.channel("forms"),
      "submit:response",
      this.actionSubmit
    );
  },

  actionSubmit: function (response) {
    const errorNotice = document.querySelector(".nf-before-form nf-section");
    errorNotice.innerHTML = "";

    if (!response.errors || !response.errors.length) {
      return;
    }

    const errors = response.errors;

    errorNotice.insertAdjacentHTML(
      "afterbegin",
      "<strong>Your form submission encountered the following errors:</strong>"
    );

    errorNotice.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<ul>");
    errors.forEach((error) => {
      errorNotice.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<li>${error}</li>`);
    });
    errorNotice.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "</ul>");

    errorNotice.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  }
});

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  new mySubmitController();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I actually ended up just scrapping NF and coding it myself and it ended up actually working better. I'll still accept since this could be useful to someone else.